# How scanf knows when to end a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int arr[2];
   arr[0] = 0;
   arr[1] = 0;
   int end = 0;
   int i;   
   for (i=0; i<2 ; i++){
      scanf(" num %d", &arr[i]);
   }

  scanf(" end %d", &end);
  printf("arr0 %d \n", arr[0]);
  printf("arr1 %d \n", arr[1]);
  printf("end  %d \n", end);

}
```

For the input:

```
num 1
num 2
end 3
```

It works perfectly fine.
But it also works for the next input:

```
num 1
end 2
```

How does it know to end the for loop and evaluate the last scanf? Why doesn't it fail?

Comment: I don't get how you even distinguish between the  "two inputs". How you terminate the second one?

Comment: There no direct relation between scanf function and for loop keyword in language C. Plus, I don't get how you can have your second input with the same code.

Comment: You should to know, when scanf finshs: use return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` DOES fail in the second example. The second loop iteration fails and returns 0 items read leaving `arr[1]` unchanged. The loop then ends and the last `scanf` successfully reads the second line of input.